# how to scan for certain character with scanner(system.in)

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm new to java programming. I tried to make calculator that can do 4 basic math operations using if statement. However I don't have it working as expected. When trying to parse operator, it just finishes with else statement.

I guess I have not properly formatted if statement ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;

public class calc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Test kalkulator za  sabiranje");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double fnum, snum, res;
    String ch = "";


    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
    fnum = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter operation: ");
    ch = keyboard.next();

    if( ch == "+") {

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        res = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println("Result is: "+ res);

    }

    else if ( ch == "-") {

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        res = fnum - snum;
        System.out.println("Result is: "+ res);
    }

    else if ( ch == "/") {

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        res = fnum / snum;
        System.out.println("Result is: "+ res);
    }

    else if( ch == "*") {

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = keyboard.nextDouble();
        res = fnum * snum;
        System.out.println("Result is: "+ res);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You entered wrong operator, please try again");
    }
    keyboard.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You're not comparing your strings properly. Since you're storing the operator in a String, you need to use `.equals()` instead of `==`. Example: `if (ch.equals("+"))` as opposed to `if (ch == "+")`

Answer (score 3):

String objects are reference objects, meaning when you type out code like

```
str == "+"
```

you're checking to see if the point in memory where str is located is equal to +. To verify if two strings equate each other, you need to use the method .equals like so

```
str.equals("+")
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. But could I use char instead of string and compare char inside if statement ?

Comment: If you're comparing a string with another string, you need to use the .equals method. If you're comparing two chars, you can use the == comparator.

From this, I feel like it's important to state that you can always check if two variables have equal value using == IF they are primitive data types. Anything else needs to be compared through more complicated methods.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `==` you should use `equals` method

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the problem is when you compare `ch` with the strings "+","-", and so on...
In java strings are Objects. Comparing objects with the `==` operator would only return true if the objects referrring to the same object. In order to actually compare the two objects you need to use the `equals()` method.
So to sum up, the correct conditions should be:
`if(ch.equals("+")){ }`
for every comparison.